# How to Make up for Mediocre STEM GPA? Will Postbac Help?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, gpa, psychology, stem

I am a senior in college majoring in cognitive science and considering grad programs in neuroscience/cognitive science. Long story short, I didn't do super well in a lot of the STEM classes I took. Specifically, I got a B- in intro programming and C+ in intro computer science, C in gen chem (A- in lab though), and C- in orgo. I've gotten B's and B+'s in every math class I took (intensive intro stats and calc up to multivariable).

I've gotten A's in most major classes (related to cog sci), A-'s and B+'s in biology classes.

Overall, my GPA is hovering around a 3.3.

I definitely tried hard in my classes- I think some of the bad grades are due to mental health struggles related to personal and family crises, others due to me turning in problem sets late (i.e. would've gotten A's on most of them but got points off for lateness). So the problem was rarely me struggling with the material.

I don't feel confident in terms of applying to grad school, so I'm seeking advice from anyone who's been in a similar position. Can a good GRE score, research experience, and good rec letters make up for these bad grades? Will I need to do a postbac or something extra to enhance my chances of getting into a neuroscience/cognitive science PhD program?

Also, will the fact that I am at Yale make any difference or not really?

Thanks!